# Python - Check if user is in team or not

Tags: python, django

I have a model that stores teams and members. I want to check if a requested user is in this team or not. How do i do that?

**Model**

```
class TeamPlayer(models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name='players', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    player = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='player', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**Template**

```
{% if request.user in object.players.all %}
      <a href="{% url 'teams:leave' pk=object.id %}" class="btn btn-warning">Leave</a>
{% else %}
      <a href="{% url 'teams:join' pk=object.id %}" class="btn btn-success">Join</a>
{% endif %}
```

**View** is just simple **DetailView**.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that in the template, just use the teamplayer_set like this:

```
{% if request.user in object.teamplayer_set.all %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i think there is no difference between object.teamplayer_set.all and object.players.all

Answer (score 0):

You have it 1-on-1, so it should be

```
players = TeamPlayer.object.all()
if request.user.player in players
    # Do what you need to
```

or in template

```
{% if request.user.player in players %}
```

provided `players` is sent to the template

When it's one-on-one, it's always `user.player` to get related player and `player.user` for the related user.